# GRUB doesn't start Windows 10

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-7, windows-10

I have a PC with Windows 7 and recently updated with Windows 10.

After the update, I installed Ubuntu with GRUB on another partition

But GRUB doesn't start Windows 10. I can see Windows7 in the GRUB menu but when I select it, I get a black screen with just `_` symbol in white.

I have tried to re-install Ubuntu, but I still have the same problem. I have tried to repair Windows and it says that an update is apparently ongoing and the partition is locked...

Comment: Did you turn off Windows 10 always on hibernation or what it calls fast start? Grub cannot boot Windows that is hibernated nor if it needs chkdsk. IF BIOS install you may have to temporarily restore the Windows boot loader with your Windows repair/restore disk. Or  use Boot-Repair. And then use Boot-Repair to restore grub to MBR after Windows fixed. Grub only boots working Windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation and: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324331&p=13488472#post13488472

Answer (score 0):

windows 10 users different boot record style GPT.

> You can not install it to a drive with a Master Boot Record (MBR)
>   Windows 10 uses GPT which is far better for large hard drives. GPT
>   supports more than 4 partition entrys and huge hard drives

i hope this link can help you
http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable **Secure Boot mode** in the BIOS.
Shutdown your PC, than reboot and continue pressing F2 before GRUB starts, to access BIOS configuration page. Than disable Secure Boot (it may ask you for a password), save and reboot. For me it worked.

Comment: Thanks. After many manipulations, I have start from scratch :) And I will try to not install Windows, only PlayOnLinux or VM ;)